# trying to get small star rater in custom list view to work

Tags: android, android-xml, android-adapter

I have a custom listview I am building, with a starbar. I had my custom listview working before I tried addign the starbar. THe force close I am getting is:

```
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class linearLayout
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at com.example.beerportfoliopro.TasteInfoAdapter.getView(TasteInfoAdapter.java:36)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2410)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1963)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:815)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:876)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1813)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2238)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13900)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4391)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13900)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4391)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13900)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4391)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13900)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4391)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13900)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4391)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2183)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1984)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1221)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4710)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:746)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:572)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:538)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:731)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.linearLayout
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
07-02 11:40:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21359):    ... 45 more
```

My custom adapter is:

```
public class TasteInfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TasteInfo>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    List<TasteInfo> data = null;

    public TasteInfoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<TasteInfo> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        beerHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new beerHolder();
            holder.txtTaste = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.breweryName);
            holder.txtRate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.breweryRate);
            holder.txtBar = (RatingBar) row.findViewById(R.id.starbar);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (beerHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        TasteInfo beer = data.get(position);
        holder.txtTaste.setText(beer.taste);
        holder.txtRate.setText(beer.rate);

        holder.numHolder= Float.parseFloat(beer.rate);

        holder.txtBar.setNumStars(5);
        holder.txtBar.setRating(holder.numHolder);

        return row;
    }

    static class beerHolder
    {
        TextView txtTaste;
        TextView txtRate;
        RatingBar txtBar;
        Float numHolder;
    }
}
```

My xml for my listview item is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breweryName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <linearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >


        <RatingBar android:id="@+id/starbar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/breweryRate"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </linearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Update:

Fixed the not putting widdth or height in the linear layout and now I get this force close:

```
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class linearLayout
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at com.example.beerportfoliopro.TasteInfoAdapter.getView(TasteInfoAdapter.java:36)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2410)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1963)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:815)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:876)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1813)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2238)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13900)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4391)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13900)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4391)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13900)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4391)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13900)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4391)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13900)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4391)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2183)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1984)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1221)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4710)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:746)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:572)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:538)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:731)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.linearLayout
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
07-02 12:33:05.162: E/AndroidRuntime(32646):    ... 45 more
```

What I am trying to accomplish is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUSRP.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <linearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
```

you missed two mandatory attribute:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: fixed one force close but brought another one

Comment: How about "LinearLayout" instead of "linearLayout"?

Comment: I am an idiot, thanks! My stars are still pretty big but I think I can figure that out.